# How to use DateTime.Date() method correctly?

Tags: apex

```
String dtString = '"'+ String.valueOf(Date.today()) + 'T00:00:00.000Z"';
DateTime dt = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize(dtString, DateTime.class);
System.debug(dt); //This prints 2016-08-30 00:00:00
System.debug(dt.date()); //This prints 2016-08-29 00:00:00
System.assert(dt.date() == System.now().date());
```

Not sure what is wrong with the above code, it keeps failing. As you can see on line 3 and 4 the debug statement prints different values.

I referred to this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/parsing-an-iso-8601-timestamp-to-a-datetime) on how to properly de-serialize a datetime.

Comment: Just curious if you are tied to the format in `dtString`, if this is all hypothetical, etc?

Comment: This is not hypothetical :) I have a valid use case.

Comment: But really, can you change the format? Using `Datetime.valueOf` would be more reliable.

Comment: @AdrianLarson,  Not sure if I understand your comment correctly but the return type for `Datetime.valueOf` is `DateTime` but I need in string format which can be desrialized into Datetime.

Comment: But *why* does it have to be deserialization?

Comment: I am deserializing a json string into custom object and it has a datetime field. FYI: This is in Test class for creating test data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime.Date() returns the local time zone's date, which you're then converting into GMT by adding T00:00:00.000Z; in effect, dt is now rounded to the nearest date in GMT format. For example, if you run this at 8pm MST, you're four hours off, but if you run this at 1pm MST, then you're 13 hours off in the other direction. You'll notice that dt.date() is again returning the date in your local time zone; midnight GMT is still the previous day for the Western half of the world. However, DateTime.now() is always expressed in GMT, which means that it's again "tomorrow" from the code's point of view. Coincidentally, if you ran this code in the morning, your assertion would pass. Alternatively, if you used DateTime.dateGMT(), you'd get the correct date in your string, and there wouldn't be a time zone skew.

Comment: This solved the problem for me.  I used something like this to construct the time part `DateTime nowDT = System.now();
String timeString = String.valueOf(nowDT.hour()) + ':' + String.valueOf(nowDT.minute()) + ':' + String.valueOf(nowDT.second());
`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use **System methods** because they work **faster**! The difference is quit small, until you are calling these methods millions of times:
For Date.today(), the cost per invocation is about 4.43µs, whereas System.today() costs about 3.85µs per invocation, a difference of about **~15%.**
For Datetime.now(), the cost per invocation is about 3.48µs, whereas System.now() costs about 2.97µs per invocation, a difference of **~17%.**