# Parse error from CSV static resource

Tags: unit-test, date, static-resources, csv

I'm getting 'CSV Parse error 2016-12-02 13:45:21 is not a valid value for the type xds:dateTime' from compiler.

I've done sample test data in CSV file according to: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm
I added column 'LastViewedDate' with the date: '2016-12-02 13:45:21'.
MIME-Type of this static resource is 'application/vnd.ms-excel' and I can't change but is still supported according to documentation.

What is the proper dateTime format of this field or file?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I use JSON library to parse datetime fields. Check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/138934/16304

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [ISO 8601 date formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) in the CSV.

So your `2016-12-02 13:45:21` becomes `2016-12-02T13:45:21.000Z`.

The following CSV resource worked for me to set both the LastViewedDate and CreatedDate.

> Name,Website,Phone,BillingStreet,BillingCity,BillingState,BillingPostalCode,BillingCountry,LastViewedDate,CreatedDate
>   sForceTest1,http://www.sforcetest1.com,(415) 901-7000,The Landmark @ One Market,San Francisco,CA,94105,US,2016-12-02T13:45:21.000Z,2016-11-02T13:45:21.000Z
>   sForceTest2,http://www.sforcetest2.com,(415) 901-7000,The Landmark @ One Market Suite 300,San Francisco,CA,94105,US,2016-12-02T13:45:21.000Z,2016-11-02T13:45:21.000Z
>   sForceTest3,http://www.sforcetest3.com,(415) 901-7000,1 Market St,San Francisco,CA,94105,US,2016-12-02T13:45:21.000Z,2016-11-02T13:45:21.000Z