# What is the correct format in mulesoft to update a date datatype field in salesforce through upsert API

Tags: rest-api

I have tried the date formats listed in the Salesforce documentation for updating a date datatype field from Mulesoft into Salesforce but they all have been rejected as invalid for datatype. I tried 2019-07-01, 2019-07-01Z, and 2019-07-01-0800. I also tried many of the datetime formats and they were also rejected.  What should my dates look like in JSON to correctly update Salesforce Date fields.  These fields are NOT datetime fields. This is my input and output json with cleaned data.I am using a multiple row upsert on the account object
Input to dw 2 transform

{

"accounts": [

```
{

  "brokertype": "Agency",

  "name": "XXX XXX Inc",

  "PHP_Broker_ID?": "888888",

  "National_Producer_Number": "8888888",

  "Original_Appointment_Date?": "2017-01-01",

  "Phone?": "5555555555",

}
```

]

}

Current dw2 output

[

{

```
"Type": "Company",

"RecordTypeId": "0126A000000ycAiQAI",

"Name": "XXX XXX Inc",

"BillingStreet": "",

"Phone": "5555555555",

"Fax": "",

"Description": "",

"Agency_IDs__c": "888888",

"National_Producer_Number__c": "8888888",

"Original_Appointment_Effective_Date__c": "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z",
```

}

]

Comment: What does your JSON look like and what Salesforce API are you calling - please update your question rather than replying to this comment.

Answer (score 1):

The expected format depends if the field (`Original_Appointment_Effective_Date__c`) is a Date or DateTime type. From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_date_format.htm) for Bulk API (the same format rules apply to standard REST APIs):

> Use the `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS+/-HHmm` or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ`
>   formats to specify `dateTime` fields.
>
> Use the `yyyy-MM-dd+/-HHmm` or `yyyy-MM-ddZ` formats to specify `date`
>   fields.
>
> - `yyyy` is the four-digit year
> - `MM` is the two-digit month (01-12)
> - `dd` is the two-digit day (01-31)
> - `'T'` is a separator indicating that time-of-day follows
> - `HH` is the two-digit hour (00-23)
> - `mm` is the two-digit minute (00-59)
> - `ss` is the two-digit seconds (00-59)
> - `SSS` is the optional three-digit milliseconds (000-999)
> - `+/-HHmm` is the Zulu (UTC) time zone offset
> - `'Z'` is the reference UTC timezone .

If your field is a DateTime, you should be sending `"2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"`.
If your field is a Date, send `"2017-01-01Z"`

See this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/parsing-an-iso-8601-timestamp-to-a-datetime) for code you can use to test the conversion.