# Invalid date/time issue in Apex Code

Tags: apex, webservices, datetime, exception

I am working on a REST API integration class and it is passing a field called effectiveDate as part of the response. However, the data in the field is not consistent. Sometimes, it is passing the value as '1985-01-01 00:00:00.000' (UTC format) and sometimes it is passing the value as '1985-01-01T00:00:00' (ISO 8601 format). In my Response class, I have defined this field as shown below.

```
public String effectiveDate {get; set;}
```

In the apex class, I am trying to populate this date on the Asset object. Below is my code.

```
Datetime effectiveDt = Datetime.parse(wsResponse.effectiveDate);   //Statement throwing exception
template.effectiveDate = Date.newInstance(effectiveDt.yearGmt(), effectiveDt.monthGmt(), effectiveDt.dayGmt());
```

However, my statement with the Datetime.parse is throwing the following exception.

```
07:40:24:715 FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 1985-12-01T00:00:00
```

How can I modify my statement to accept the Datetime irrespective of whether it is coming in UTC format or ISO8601 format?

EDIT:
I have tried the following piece of code in execute anonymous window and I am getting the error message as [Line: 15, Column: 1
System.JSONException: Invalid format: "2019-01-01 11:50:55" is malformed at " 11:50:55"].

**EDIT**: Changed the month and date in the below dates.

```
String strDate1 = '2017-12-17T11:50:50.000Z';
String strDate2 = '2016-11-16 11:50:55';

Datetime date1 = (Datetime)JSON.deserialize('"' + strDate1 + '"',Datetime.class);
Datetime date2 = (Datetime)JSON.deserialize('"' + strDate2 + '"',Datetime.class);

System.debug('date 1 = ' + date1);
System.debug('date 2 = ' + date2); Date.newInstance(date1.yearGmt(),date1.monthGmt(),date1.dayGmt()));
System.debug('Date 2 = ' + Date.newInstance(date2.yearGmt(),date2.monthGmt(),date2.dayGmt()));
```

**Output of debug log**:

```
17:54:48:005 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|date 1 = 2017-01-01 00:00:00
17:54:48:005 USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|date 2 = 2016-01-01 00:00:00
17:54:48:006 USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|Date 1 = 2017-01-01 00:00:00
17:54:48:006 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|Date 2 = 2016-01-01 00:00:00
```

As you can see, the month and day are always coming as 01 instead of 12 and 11 that we are passing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

deserializing  your  datetime (both utc  & ISO)  in datetime.class  should solve the issue.
JSON.desrialize('datetime' , Datetime.class);

i have tested  both format  in anynomous block and it is working fine.

```
Datetime effectiveDt = (Datetime) JSON.deserialize('1985-01-01 00:00:00.000',Datetime.class);
system.debug(Date.newInstance(effectiveDt.yearGmt(), effectiveDt.monthGmt(), effectiveDt.dayGmt()));


Datetime effectiveDtISO = (Datetime) JSON.deserialize('1985-01-01T00:00:00',Datetime.class);
system.debug(Date.newInstance(effectiveDtISO.yearGmt(), effectiveDtISO.monthGmt(), effectiveDtISO.dayGmt()));
```

Credits  go to this thread which i have referred :  [Parsing an ISO 8601 timestamp to a DateTime](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/parsing-an-iso-8601-timestamp-to-a-datetime)

OP Example modified

```
String strDate1 = '2020-01-01T11:50:50.000Z';
String strDate2 = '2019-01-01 11:50:55';

Datetime date1 = (Datetime)JSON.deserialize( strDate1 ,Datetime.class);
Datetime date2 = (Datetime)JSON.deserialize( strDate2 ,Datetime.class);

System.debug('Date 1 = ' + Date.newInstance(date1.yearGmt(),date1.monthGmt(),date1.dayGmt()));
System.debug('Date 2 = ' + Date.newInstance(date2.yearGmt(),date2.monthGmt(),date2.dayGmt()));
```

OP mentioned that day and month i always showing 01.
2 points:

1. datetime string will be needed in double quotes (  my mistake i disregarded that previously)
2. deserialize method is only working with proper iso  format  after using double  hence we can check  if date  is in iso format   then deserialize  it  otherwise  just  get value of datetime  using  datetime.valueof

String strDate1 = '2017-12-17T11:50:50.000Z';
String strDate2 = '2016-11-16 11:50:55';

Datetime date1 = (DateTime)(strDate1.contains('T')?(Datetime)JSON.deserialize('"' +  strDate1 + '"' ,Datetime.class) : DateTime.valueof(strDate1));
Datetime date2 = (Datetime)(strDate2.contains('T')?(Datetime)JSON.deserialize('"' +  strDate2 + '"' ,Datetime.class) : DateTime.valueof(strDate2));

System.debug('date 1 = ' + date1);
System.debug('date 2 = ' + date2);
System.debug('date11 = ' + Date.newInstance(date1.yearGmt(),date1.monthGmt(),date1.dayGmt()));
System.debug('Date 21 = ' + Date.newInstance(date2.yearGmt(),date2.monthGmt(),date2.dayGmt()));

======================================================================
**Updated Solution**

```
String strDate1 = '2020-01-01T11:50:50.000Z';
Datetime strDate1 = (strDate1==null)?null:Datetime.valueOf(strDate1.replace('T',' '));
Datetime date1 = Date.newInstance(strDate1.yearGmt(),strDate1.monthGmt(),strDate1.dayGmt());
```

======================================================================
And, this solution works perfectly irrespective of whether the date comes in ISO8601 format or UTC format.

Comment: It does not work for me, I will update the original post with my anonymous code block.

Comment: why you have added double quotes  in deserilize.  you are deserializing   vriable   not string literal.  please remove that.  refer to updated answer.

Comment: I am adding double quotes because the JSON.deserialize() method expects a string literal. After removing the double quotes, I am getting the error message [Line: 15, Column: 1
System.JSONException: Invalid format: "2019-01-01 11:50:55" is malformed at " 11:50:55"].

Comment: i have already  updated your example in my answer.  i tested it.it is working  fine.  are you facing any issue in your modifed example   added in my answer?

Comment: Your code is working fine, when I copy pasted it in execute anonymous window. However, when I do the same thing in my Apex class, I am not sure what's going on, but the entire trigger/integration class is not getting triggered. How can we debug when there is no entry in the debug log?

Comment: i have provided resolution for the datetime conversion issue you were facing.  i cannot comment on your complete code.    if   you are facing any issue in your code. add system.debug  at speciifc places.   set up a debug log on user   who will execute the logic  it might be your integration user and anlyze generted debug logs

Comment: It is actually a platform event trigger. We are using the Pub-Sub model. The third party service is sending the webservice response. We have a .NET middleware application that reads the response from Nservicebus and makes a REST callout to insert a record into a platform event object using metadata API. The trigger on the platform event object is calling a helper class which makes another callout to the third party system to get more details which is were my date logic is being handled. I have setup debug logs for Automated Process, but there is nothing in the logs.

Comment: it should come  under automated process logs if it is working fine.i  dont have any other suggestion apart from what you are already  doing as it is the correct way.make sure integration is working.

Comment: Found the issue. The 24 hours time limit has passed for "Automated Process" debug log entry. I have enabled it again and now it is working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found a new issue with the code that I am using to covert the string date into Datetime using JSON.deserialize() method. When we use the JSON.deserialize, the month and day are always returned as 1 and 1 respectively, irrespective of whatever we pass. I have updated the original post to explain this issue.

Comment: thanks  for pointing it out.  i had not  tested with many test cases.  you  would need double quotes as you were using  previously  my mistake here to remove that  and it will not workfor  datetime not containg  T   hence you can check if datetime contains T  then desrilize  otherwise   directly get value.   please find updated answer.   you can aslo       refer to original reference   if it helps you.

Comment: I wrote it little differently and it worked fine. See my updated answer in the OP.